# Where does Netbeans read files from?

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm trying to read from a text file in Netbeans. In the top level of my project directory I have foo.txt. Then in my code I have:

```
File file = new File("foo.txt");
```

It throws a `FileNotFoundException`, however. It's a Java web application using Spring and Tomcat, but I'm not sure if those details matter since I'm running the whole thing inside Netbeans. Basically, I just want to know where I need to put the file so Netbeans will read it.

Update - good call guys, it's looking in Tomcat's bin directory. Now this may be a stupid question but, how would I go about getting it to look in my top level project directory? I feel like dropping text files into tomcat's bin would be innapropriate.

Comment: The code you posted can only throw `NullPointerException`. It's something else that's throwing `FileNotFoundException`.

Comment: True, it's the scanner object that I create with that file later on that throws the FileNotFound I believe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To directly answer your question, If you're running an application on Tomcat, files will be opened from the *current working directory*.  That will likely be the `bin/` folder in your `tomcat` directory.

You can find out for sure where your program is looking by examining the result of `file.getAbsolutePath()`.

However, for web applications, I would suggest putting files you need to read in your classpath so you don't have to depend on a certain file structure when you deploy your web application.

Answer (score 5):

You can try printing the absolute path of the `File` object to see where it is looking on the filesystem.

```
System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
```

Answer (score 4):

I would use the following to figure out where to put the file:

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
```

Answer (score 0):

try `System.getProperty("user.dir")` to get current working directory